# Paypal advanced payment method error with Magento ver. 1.12.0.2

Tags: payment, paypal

I have configured all the necessary info for Paypal advanced payment method in Magento properly. But when the customer try to checkout with Paypal advanced payment method. It returns following error

```
    Notice: Undefined property: Mage_Paypal_PayflowadvancedController::$_configType  in /home/storedev12/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Controller/Express/Abstract.php on line 53

#0 /home/storedev12/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Controller/Express/Abstract.php(53): mageCoreErrorHandler(8, 'Undefined prope...', '/home/storedev1...', 53, Array)
#1 /home/storedev12/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(145): Mage_Paypal_Controller_Express_Abstract->_construct()
#2 /home/storedev12/public_html/app/Mage.php(504): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->__construct(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Response_Http), Array)
#3 /home/storedev12/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(202): Mage::getControllerInstance('Mage_Paypal_Pay...', Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Response_Http))
#4 /home/storedev12/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#5 /home/storedev12/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#6 /home/storedev12/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /home/storedev12/public_html/index.php(91): Mage::run('retail', 'website')
#8 {main}
```

does anybody knows what could be wrong here?

note: 
I have ticket open with Magento support for last 2 days :(

Comment: Did you find an answer here? Please mark it as solution. If not, did you solve your issue? Share the details with us please!

Answer (score 3):

To stop this message from showing up you will need to suppress errors from showing. This can be done in the index.php file of your magento installations root folder.

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}

// ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Above is what it should look like.

Comment: This is not actually a solution. it's just a way to 'hide the dirt under the rug'.

Answer (score 2):

It seams that `Mage_Paypal_PayflowadvancedController` is not configured correctly. Sounds like a Magento bug. It's missing 2 protected members needed to initialize the payment method: `$_configType` and `$_configMethod`.

Try adding this to the `Mage_Paypal_PayflowadvancedController` class and test the payment process:

```
protected $_configType = 'paypal/config';
protected $_configMethod = Mage_Paypal_Model_Config::METHOD_PAYFLOWADVANCED;
```

I'm just shooting in the dark here. Don't get mad if it doesn't work.

Comment: +1, This hasn't been marked as correct but it is exactly the right answer for this issue and there are not many other references to it on Google.